# NgRX 'No overload matches this call'

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am struggling to set up Ngrx in my Angular 16 app. I think I have the actions/reducers/selectors configured correctly but when I make a call to this.store.select() in my component I get an error.

The error:

```
    /mypage.component.ts:29:42 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 9, '(mapFn: (state: object) => unknown): Observable<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: object) => unknown'.
  Overload 2 of 9, '(key: never): Observable<never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

 entry_one = this.store.select('selectEntryOne')
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'd appreciate any help, I must have made a mistake somewhere...

app/models/data.ts

```
export interface Data {
    entry_one: any;
    entry_two: any;
}
```

app/pages/mypage.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectEntryOne, selectEntryTwo } from '@state/selectors/data.selectors';

export class MyPageComponent {

  // Grab values from Global Store. Not Working.
  entry_one: this.store.select('selectEntryOne');
  entry_two: this.store.select('selectEntryTwo');


  constructor( private store: Store ){ }
  
  }
```

app/state/selectors/data.selectors.ts

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '@state/app.state';
import { DataState } from '@state/reducers/data.reducers';

export const selectData = (state: AppState) => state.data;

export const selectEntryOne = createSelector(
    selectData,
    (state: DataState) => state.data.entry_one
);

export const selectEntryTwo = createSelector(
    selectData,
    (state: DataState) => state.data.entry_two
);
```

app/state/reducers/data.reducers.ts

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { setData } from '@state/actions/data.actions'
import { Data } from '@models/data';

export interface DataState {
    data: Data;
    status: 'start' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'success';
    error: string;
}

export const initialState: DataState = {
    data: {
        entry_one: 100,
        entry_two: 100,
    },
    status: 'start',
    error: ''
}

export const dataReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(setEntryOne, (state, { data }) => ({
        ...state,
        data: { ...state.data, entry_one: data.entry_one },
    })),
    on(setEntryTwo, (state, { data }) => ({
        ...state,
        data: { ...state.data, entry_two: data.entry_two },
    })),
```

app/state/actions/data.actions.ts

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Data } from '@models/data';

export const setEntryOne = createAction(
    '[EntryOne Data] Set Entry One',
    props<{ data: Data }>()
);

export const setEntryTwo = createAction(
    '[EntryTwo Data] Set Entry two',
    props<{ data: Data }>()
);
```

In my app.module.ts I have `StoreModule.forRoot({ data: dataReducer })`

I am completely stumped! Maybe my selectors are wrong? Maybe I have to call them another way?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with my AppState ? In the Mypage component I have constructor( private store: Store ){ } but I see other posts with store: Store<Data>

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm thinking I have stitched this whole thing together wrong or something. I'm going to give up and start again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this file: `app/pages/mypage.component.ts`, do this intead:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectEntryOne, selectEntryTwo } from '@state/selectors/data.selectors';

export class MyPageComponent {

  // Grab values from Global Store. Not Working. => Remove the quotes around selectors name
  entry_one: this.store.select(selectEntryOne);
  entry_two: this.store.select(selectEntryTwo);


  constructor( private store: Store ){ }
  
  }
```

Notice that I removed the quotes around selectors! Means that you should pass selectors as they are imported, not as strings!

Comment: Thanks for the info. It results in a very similar error message. Instead of 'unknown' it is 'Data'. No overload matches this call. 
Overload 1 of 9, '(mapFn: (state: object) => Data): Observable<Data>'

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 errors in the `app/pages/mypage.component.ts`

1. as Mugirase Emmanuel already said, selectors must be imported and not called by strings:
2. `entry_one` and `entry_two` are not a `this.store.select(....);` type! Following you code they should be both `any`

The updated code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectEntryOne, selectEntryTwo } from '@state/selectors/data.selectors';

export class MyPageComponent {

// or assign them later
entry_one: Observable<any> = this.store.select(selectEntryOne);
entry_two: Observable<any> = this.store.select(selectEntryTwo);


constructor( private store: Store ){ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still results in an error. I'm thinking it may be something to do with the  props in the actions file.

Comment: Overload 1 of 9, '(mapFn: (state: Data) => DataState): Observable<DataState>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<AppState, DataState, (s1: DataState) => DataState>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: Data) => DataState'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.